# How to find maximum number of such pairs of connected edges in a graph that each pair is separated from another pair by at least two edges?

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching

I need to find maximum number of pairs of connected edges in a graph such that each pair is separated from every other pair by at least two edges. This could be seen as the maximum matching without the constraint of covering all edges where each component in the alternating path is with length 2.

Clarification of terms:

1. Connected pairs: Pairs of edges must be in the same connected component.
2. Connected pairs: Two paired edges do not necessarily need to share a vertex.
3. Each pair is separated by at least two edges: Given pairs [(u<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>), (u<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>)] and [(u<sub>3</sub>, v<sub>3</sub>), (u<sub>4</sub>, v<sub>4</sub>)], the minimum distance between u ∈ {u<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>, u<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>} and v ∈ {u<sub>3</sub>, v<sub>3</sub>, u<sub>4</sub>, v<sub>4</sub>} is no less than two?
4. Each **pair** is separated by at least two edges: Given pairs [(u<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>1</sub>), (u<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>)] and [(u<sub>3</sub>, v<sub>3</sub>), (u<sub>4</sub>, v<sub>4</sub>)], the minimum distance between, say u<sub>1</sub> and u<sub>2</sub> can be anything, including zero (the same vertex)?

Comment: As per the comments in j_random_hacker's answer, could you please review the clarification of terms again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way to do it would be to create a new graph G' in which you have a vertex for every pair of connected edges in G, and an edge connects two vertices in G' whenever the corresponding edge pairs in G are less than 2 edges apart.  You could then look for a [maximum independent set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29) in G'.

This is far from ideal, since G' will be huge and independent set is NP-complete.  If you can show that G' has some special structure, you might be able to do much better though.  E.g., if it is necessarily bipartite, then [König's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29) will let you find a maximum independent set in polynomial time using maximum matching.  (This will still be very slow in practice, as there could be O(m^2) vertices...)

Comment: Awesome answer. Forgot to say that G is actually bipartite but of course G' could be anything. So do you think this problem might be NP-complete? I was wondering if the hopcroft-karp could be somehow modified for that purpose. (Upvote as soon as I get enough reputation)

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, it turns out that this problem is NP-complete after all: it's possible to reduce Independent Set to this problem.  I'll post a proof as a separate answer; it's a bit longwinded.

Comment: Independent set on a bipartite graph is soluble. Also, while your G' has O(m^2) verts, the final answer can't be larger than n/3. I don't think you should give up yet, @j_random_hacker.

Comment: @Kittsil: I found a mistake in my reduction (which basically involves creating a 3-vertex, 2-edge gadget for each vertex in the IS instance, and then "cross-linking" all gadget vertices whenever they are linked by an edge in the IS instance), so you may be right...  But I might yet figure it out...

Comment: I think I've come up with a reduction to the [k-path partition problem](http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~monnot/index_fichiers/rev/Pathpartition.pdf) which is NP-complete even on bipartite graphs.   We first create a line graph L(G), edges of which are actually all different pairs of incident edges in G. Perfect matching in a line graph always corresponds to the original graph. Thus pairs of edges are adjecent in G but not overlapping. Now if we increase the gaps of the perfect matching in L(G) to length 3 then the edge pairs  should be separated by 2 edges in G.

Comment: So we can turn this problem into finding a 4-path partition in L(G). The edges joining the paths are the ones we are after.

Comment: You reduced this to k path partition; a complexity proof would go the other way. There is still hope!

Comment: @j_random_hacker Very nice answer. From what I remember, some of the approximation algorithms could perhaps be performed on the original graph G, avoiding generating G'.

Comment: @Kittsil: Although your edit to the original question does clarify terms, it clarifies them in an unexpected way I think!  I had assumed that the 2 edges *did* need to share (exactly) 1 vertex.  (Yes, even though this goes against the standard graph theory meaning of "connected".  My reasoning being that most people besides graph theorists would use the term in this way.  Do you know the OP's intended meaning for sure?)

Comment: @j_random_hacker No, but I did ask the OP to review them before accepting the edits. If it is instead that they need to share one vertex, the problem becomes significantly more straightforward (and the number of vertices in your G' can't be more than O(n^2)).

Comment: @Kittsil: I see.  But O(n^3) one-vertex-sharing edges are possible though.  (Suppose G is a complete bipartite graph with n/2 vertices in each part: pick any two distinct vertices in part A and any vertex in part B to get a vertex in G'.  Which is admittedly less than the O(m^2) that I originally claimed, but still more than your O(n^2).)